# How to assign Websphere Shared libraries to project?

Tags: java, websphere-7

I have successfully created a Shared Library and deployed the EAR in WAS 7.

Before starting the application I have tried to assign the already created Shared Library to the project. But I'm getting the following error:

> com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message -
>   [isclite#isclite.war]:.action: ApplicationDeploymentDetailForm was
>   null.Creating new form bean and storing in session.

Could you please give some suggestion to fix this issue?

Comment: The manual lists two high level steps for shared libraries -- creating them and associating them with installed applications.  Did you have some difficulty associating it with your application, or have you not tried?  

I don't see the relevance of the informational message you included.

Comment: @covener I have successfully created the shared library. When I try to add it to project getting above error and in configuration UI I cannot move the library to left to right with an arrow sign.

Comment: Project? Are you doing this in an IDE?

Comment: @covener  Thanks for your reply 
I have tried two options.
1. Create the EAR with maven and deployed it using WAS admin console
2. Export the EAR from the IDE(RAD) and deployed it using WAS admin console
Both options are gave the same error.

Comment: Check this link - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21203410 maybe your application is already installed under ear, with same name. For example it is added in RAD via Add/Remove to server? Ensure there are no applications installed and retry.